# Mathematica script - Using front end

Tags: front-end, mac-os-x, scripting

I'm running *Mathematica* on OS X and I want to create an Automator action that converts spreadsheet files. I have written this script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script

FORMATS = {"csv", "tsv", "dat", "xls", "xlsx", "odf"};
files = Rest @ $ScriptCommandLine;
data = Import /@ files;
{ext, delete} = 
  DialogInput[
   DialogNotebook @ {
     TextCell["Choose output format:"], 
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[x], FORMATS], 
     Row @ {Checkbox[Dynamic[y]], TextCell["Delete original files"]}, 
     Row @ {CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[{x, y}]]}
   }];
newNames = (FileNameJoin@{DirectoryName[#], FileBaseName[#]} <> "." <> ext)& /@ files;  
MapThread[Export, {newNames, data}];
If[delete, DeleteFile[files]];
```

When I run it, I get this error message when running `DialogInput`:

> FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.

Is there any work-around, or should I try a different approach?

Comment: You're indeed using a lot of functions that require the FrontEnd. Not sure why you think you could run that *without* FrontEnd. If you want this kind of interactivity why don't you simply use a notebook?

Answer (score 6):

You can solve the issue by wrapping your code with [`UsingFrontEnd[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UsingFrontEnd.html).

Comment: I have both the script and the file in my home directory. If I run "./myScript data.csv" in terminal, I get this error "MathLink`Synchronized::noshare: -- Message text not found --
"

Comment: Sry, but it seems a different platform specific problem. When you run `UsingFrontEnd[NotebookPut[Notebook[{Cell[Text["Test"]]}]]]` in your script without the `UsingFrontEnd` you get the `FrontEndObject` error. You don't get any errors with. I do not know about the `MathLink` problem.